# python cannot convert lines read from file into list or tuple

Tags: python

consider a file named lst.txt, which contents are:`('a', ('b',('c','d')))`,when read from it and try to convert to tuple, but it returns chars;

codes:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  with open('lst.txt') as fx:
    strs = fx.readline()
    print tuple(strs)
```

the result is: `['(', "'", 'a', "'", ',', '(', "'", 'b', "'", ',', '(', "'", 'c', "'", ',', "'",
 'd', "'", ')', ')', ')', '\n']`

but if I use the python shell, result is different:

```
>>>test_str = ('a', ('b',('c','d')))
>>>result = tuple(test_str)
>>>print result
('a', ('b', ('c', 'd')))
```

why?

Comment: You know that you can format blocks of code using 4-spaces indentation?

Comment: Where did you get this file? Are you writing it yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Because the two are not equivalent, when you read from the file, your text is not parsed as python. The equivalent is doing:

```
>>>test_str = "('a', ('b',('c','d')))"
>>>result = tuple(test_str)
```

Which should make it pretty clear why you get your result. The string is iterated over and turned into a tuple, with each character being turned into an item in the tuple.

This given, what you need to do is parse the data in the file. You could do this in some obvious *bad* ways, but one secure method would be to use [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html).

Your best bet is to store the data in another format, like JSON, and then use [the `json` module](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) to get the data from the file. If you don't need it to be human readable, and know where your data is coming from and trust it, you could use use [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html?highlight=pickle#pickle) for ease of use.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I would guess it rhymes with "Tcl" and introduces bugs and security holes to your program.

Comment: Maybe because you initially suggested to use JSON or pickle, whereas `literal_eval` would be much more appropriate.

Comment: @NiklasB., I deeply doubt it. `ast.literal_eval` is a very direct answer, but it's probably due to an avoidable situation where something insane was written to the file. A good data model and serialization technique (such as JSON) makes tons more sense and is more robust, portable, and sane than writing reprs to files and hoping you can `literal_eval` them later.

Comment: @Mike: Sure, that's an argument. Depends on the use case, of course.

Comment: @NiklasB., `ast.literal_eval` is just about devoid of good usecases.

Comment: @Mike: Well, in this particular case it's not very far-fetched to suggest it.

Comment: I gave all the options. I agree that JSON is probably the better option here, but that doesn't mean I shouldn't talk about the other options available. There are uses for the other options, and if I am writing a script for my own personal use to do something simple, there is nothing wrong with using something like pickle.

Comment: Yes, there are many things wrong with using pickle. It should never be used or encouraged in any way. Pickle's design has inherent flaws affecting security, correctness, robustness, and portability.

Comment: @MikeGraham None of which matter for my 10 minute script to do something small. In the words of the Zen of Python '*practicality beats purity*'. No, don't use Pickle in a case where it matters, but where it doesn't? Why not use the easiest way?

Answer (score 0):

`testStr` is a tuple already. Try `test_str = "('a', ('b',('c','d')))"`, and you'll get the same results as with the file.

Answer (score -3):

```
('a', ('b',('c','d')))
```

this is not a str, it's already a tuple

```
>>> type(('a', ('b',('c','d'))))
<type 'tuple'>
```

try this

```
with open('lst.txt') as f:
  print eval(f.read())
```

Comment: Oh nose, please not `eval`! It's totally unnecessary and very dangerous here.